# Aggregate ArrayType column to get another ArrayType column without UDF

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I have a dataframe like this, that has one ArrayType column

```
simpleData = [("202305","Sales","NY",[1,2,3]),
    ("202306","Sales","NY",[4,2,3]),
    ("202305","Sales","CA",[4,5,3]),
    ("202306","Finance","CA",[4,5,6]),
    ("202305","Finance","NY",[5,6,7]),
    ("202306","Finance","NY",[6,7,8]),
  ]

schema = ["month","department","state","lis"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=simpleData, schema = schema)
```

What I would like to do is find the median value of the *lis* column, but grouped by some columns. Pretty much like what we would do with *percentile_approx()* over a numeric column, but here I want that to be done such that the median is computed on the unioned list for each group.

Desired output:

```
df1 = df.groupBy('department').agg(desired_function(col('lis')).alias('lis_median'))
```

gives

```
+----------+----------+
|department|lis_median|
+----------+----------+
|     Sales|         3|
|   Finance|         6|
+----------+----------+
```

I tried doing

```
df1 = df.groupBy('department').agg(collect_list(col('lis')).alias('lis_median'))
```

to atleast get the aggregated list over the group, but it only generates a list of list.

I'd like some way to implement this. I dont want to use UDF due to execution speed concerns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @notNull, flatten the list and get median according to the size.
Below is one of the approaches you can also follow.
You can use `posexplode` function which gives position and value of that list,
and do aggregate and find median directly as below.

```
display(df.selectExpr("*", "posexplode(lis) as (pos, lis_value)").groupBy('department').agg(median("lis_value").alias('lis_median')))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try with higher order functions for array i.e. `flatten,array_sort` for this case.

- if the size of array is even then get the median value from midvalue + midvalue -1/2
- if size of array is odd then get the mid value as the median

**`Example:`**

```
simpleData = [("202305","Sales","NY",[1,2,3]),
    ("202306","Sales","NY",[4,2,3]),
    ("202305","Sales","CA",[4,5,3]),
    ("202306","Finance","CA",[4,5,6]),
    ("202305","Finance","NY",[5,6,7]),
    ("202306","Finance","NY",[6,7,8]),
  ]

schema = ["month","department","state","lis"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=simpleData, schema = schema)

df.groupBy("department").agg(flatten(collect_set(col("lis"))).alias("cs")).\
  withColumn('col', array_sort(expr('filter(cs, x -> x is not null)'))).\
  withColumn('lis_median', when(size(col('cs')) % 2 == 0,
                                            (expr('col[int(size(cs)/2)]') + expr('col[int(size(cs)/2)-1]'))/2
                                            ).otherwise(expr('col[int(size(cs)/2)]'))).\
                                              drop(*['col','cs']).\
  show(10,False)
#+----------+----------+
#|department|lis_median|
#+----------+----------+
#|Sales     |3.0       |
#|Finance   |6.0       |
#+----------+----------+
```